How do I get Gradle to rebuild with vite when a file is updated?
I have a project that is using Gradle and Node to build my UI the basic task defs look like this...
def uiProjectDir = file("../ui")
def uiDistDir = file("../ui/dist")

// Task to run npm install
tasks.register('npmInstall', Exec) {
    workingDir uiProjectDir
    inputs.file("${uiProjectDir}/package.json")
    outputs.dir("${uiProjectDir}/node_modules")

    // Use bash directly when in WSL
    commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'npm install'
}

// Task to build the UI
tasks.register('buildUi', Exec) {
    workingDir uiProjectDir
    inputs.dir("${uiProjectDir}/src")
    inputs.dir("${uiProjectDir}/node_modules")
    outputs.dir(uiDistDir)
    dependsOn npmInstall

    // Use bash directly when in WSL
    commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'npm run build'
}

// Task to copy UI build artifacts to resources
tasks.register('copyUiBuild', Copy) {
    dependsOn buildUi
    from uiDistDir
    into "src/main/resources/static"
}

// Make sure the UI is built and copied before processing resources
processResources.dependsOn copyUiBuild

This works fine but I have to restart the app when I make UI changes. Is there a way I can change this to have it automagically regenerate and copy when a change is made to the UI files. If I run vite run dev it does rebuild when there are changes but I don't want to have to run that separately I would like to have everything done through the Gradle tasks and not lose relative pathing.

If you run your Gradle task with the --continuous flag it will re-run the tasks when task file inputs change on the file system (docs):
./gradlew copyUiBuild --continuous


So how would I run this when I also need to run the bootRun task for the backend. The copy one just copies to the resources for that

I tried copyUiBuild bootRun --continuous but that doesn't seem to work when I change a file it doesn't pick up the change.

The changed files need to be marked as inputs in executing tasks.
